# onmouseover event in Firefox inside SVG

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, dom-events

I have searched for the answer here, but unsuccessfully.

So, I've got  SVG inside an html page, and I'd like to catch `onmouseover` event this way:

```
<g id="node1" class="node" onmouseover="showTooltip(event,'blabla',0,200)">
```

which works file in Chrome.

To use this in Firefox I'm trying to use **Yahoo dom event** library. Using it I can catch this event in Firefox, but not inside  SVG:

> event is not defined

How can I use `onmouseover` event inside SVG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using evt rather than event. This example works in firefox: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/script/script01.svg

Comment: great! the only thing i want to know is WHY the hell EVT?

Comment: In Webkit (Chrome/Safari) and Presto (Opera) you can use either 'evt' or 'event' (evt is basically "var evt=event;"). Might be nice if Firefox made that change too.

Comment: @k102 it's `evt` because the SVG spec says so.  Now why the spec writers there decided to be incompatible with HTML, who knows.

Comment: @ErikDahlström At least in Chrome (Safari is different; this is part of V8, not WebKit), in event handlers in general the function argument is named `evt`.  Using bareword `event` just looks up the scope chain and if you're lucky lands you at `window.event` which Chrome also defines.  But if there's an expando named `event` on the element, say, you lose.  See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80912 .  Firefox is unlikely to do that, since it's pretty broken both per spec and in practice.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky ugh, worse than I thought then. Unfortunately there's quite a lot of svg content that uses 'evt', and if all browsers don't allow both 'event' and 'evt' it certainly doesn't help in deprecating 'evt'.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Are we aiming at deprecating 'evt'?  What's the endgame?  Should event handlers just be defined as getting two arguments and be done with it, perhaps?  That seems simpler than trying to deprecate stuff or the Chrome hack.